# error: "string was not in a correct format" when get I get time-stamp data...

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a windows service (C# .netframework 4.0) which connect to MySQL db. The error throw when i try to execute a command look like:

```
var cmd= new MySqlCommand("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP", Common.RemoteConnDwReadol)
                {
                    CommandType = CommandType.Text 
                };
string strtime = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

The command will be return current time-stamp of the MySQL server. Then the error detail here:

> at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style,
>   NumberFormatInfo info)    at
>   MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime.ParseMySql(String s)    at
>   MySql.Data.Types.MySqlDateTime.MySql.Data.Types.IMySqlValue.WriteValue(MySqlPacket
>   packet, Boolean binary, Object value, Int32 length)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter.Serialize(MySqlPacket packet,
>   Boolean binary, MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.SerializeParameter(MySqlParameterCollection
>   parameters, MySqlPacket packet, String parmName)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.InternalBindParameters(String sql,
>   MySqlParameterCollection parameters, MySqlPacket packet)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.BindParameters()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Statement.Execute()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
>   at TVC.Analytic.Service.Analytics.ClickView.Analyzing()  Error:Input
>   string was not in a correct format.
>
> For more information, see Help and Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

**Platform info:**
*Machine Dev:*

```
Windows 8 consumer preview x64.
.NET Framework 4.x (VS 2010)
MySQL Connector 6.5.4.0
```

Running on another machine:

```
Windows server 2003, x64
.NET Framework 4.x 
MySQL server 5.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried with mtsql 5.5 and connector 6.2.5 and it works for me.

But alternatively try it like this:

```
SELECT cast(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as char)
```